# React router descendant routes and throttling issue

Tags: reactjs, router

Below is my component tree where descendant routes are there. I actually want my page to automatically pick the path from "/" to "/login" in another component. It's not working. If I make "/login" to "/" to match the parent route am getting throttling issue and none of my navlinks are working. Please kindly help.
`code`
// Root Component

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/*" element={<AppContainer />} />      
</Routes>
```

//App Container component

```
return (<App />);
```

//App component

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/login" element={<LoginContainer />} />      
</Routes>
```

If I replace "/login" to "/" or index below code is throwing throttling browser hand issue.

```
<NavLink to="/ehmintegrate" activeClassName="navitem--active"
   isActive={(match, location) => { return location?.pathname == "/ehmintegrate" }}>
  <div>Integration</div>                         
</NavLink>
```